# How can I use netbeans database without having to create it everytime I use a different computer?

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I have a database under netbeans services tab, but I want to be able to run my application if I send it to another computer, without having to create the database again. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And how did you create the database you have?

Comment: JavaDB installation: glassfish-3.1.2.2\javadb. Database location: .netbeans-derby. I entered these after going to netbeans services tab, right click on database, create database then properties

Comment: I heard that SQLLite might be a good solution to this, is this correct?